# How would you build the spanish counterpart of "truthiness"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, diminutivos, sufijos

I stumbled upon the English term [*Truthiness*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truthiness)

> "truth" that a person claims to know intuitively "from the gut" in that it "feels right" without regard to evidence, logic, intellectual examination, or facts

I like this word very much, especially in the context of conspiracy theories.

In German you would use diminutive suffixes to minimize/belittle a word, a subjective opinion with a little bit feeled truth in it.

What spanish suffixes would you use for *verdad* to build the counterpart. I only know there are different suffixes for different word-endings. Please explain also if/how phonetic (maybe dialects - works well in German) reasons would influence your choice, so it doesn't sound too artificial.

Comment: Can you _intimidate_ a word?

Comment: Instead of using some artificial construct, in this concrete case, I would suggest using *certeza*:

certeza.
(De cierto).

 1. f. Conocimiento seguro y claro de algo.
 2. f. Firme adhesión de la mente a algo conocible, sin temor de errar.

Comment: @belisarius removed it, was given out as synonym for belittle in a dictionary

Comment: This question seems subjective to me. Is it asked how each of us would invent such a new word if we had to, or is it asking if there is one right way to invent new words in Spanish using this as an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper way to say it is the following:

> Veracidad

As kevin said his examples are very good. But I am afraid that verdaderosidad does not exist or certizidad or veracecinidad. The proper word is **veracidad** even if no so fancy as the invented versions.

As gonzalo said per comments, **certeza** is a good alternative. The problem is that in Spanish we don't have a exact translation for a word such as Truthiness. Truthiness means something that has the quality of **seeming** or **being felt** as true but is not necessarily true.

Now a word that can express the **exact** meaning of truthiness would be **intuición** but that means something that slightly diverges from the meaning. But essentially means the same.

**Intuición** is something someone feels that is true, but cannot be certain it is. So you can slightly change context to use it and make the communication of the meaning you want, effective.

**Verosímil** seems to express the exact meaning correctly. Or at least very close to it. As Juan Pablo pointed out. Check it out on the RAE.

Comment: That's a real word, though, and truthiness is not really a word (or if it is, it's a coinage). The invented aspect of it is lost in translation if a word that isn't slightly made-up is used in Spanish, and I think in this particular case it's a big loss. Also, the difference between truthiness and intuition is that truthiness implies a certain dislike for the right answer; the person just wants to believe what they believe whether it's right or not. Intuition implies that they *do* want the right answer but arrive at it differently.

Comment: Truthiness is really a word. It may be a big loss but the important thing here is that no one will understand what you mean if you say "verdaderosidad" or "certizidad" They will most likely look at you as if you are some extraterrestrial creature. I can guarantee that. In any case each language has its own ways to express an idea, not everything can be exactly translated, as I am sure there are some spanish expressions that can't be translated into english. Intuition and truthiness are different of course, but using intuición to translate truthiness is the closest you can get to the meaning.

Comment: I wasn't sure if he was asking for his own curiosity or for a real translation. If it's for a real one, then yeah, compromises will have to be made and the result won't really convey the meaning. Maybe it needs several words, like `verdad del estómago` or something :P

Comment: +1 hahaha `verdad del estómago` is a good one

Comment: @Joze. "Verosímil" fits this definition quite well: "something that has the quality of seeming or being felt as true but is not necessarily true".

Comment: @JuanPabloCalifano That is quite true! Bingo. I did not think about that word. Thanks Juan Pablo.

Comment: @Joze. My pleasure.

Answer (score 5):

Colbert Report fan, eh?

This is a tough one. I looked to color words, many of which have an `-ish` equivalent, which is what we're looking for here.

We have:

`rojizo` - reddish

`blanquizo`/`blanquecino`/`blancuzco` - whitish

`azulado` - bluish

`verdoso` - greenish

`negruzco` - blackish

`amarillente/amarilloso` - yellowish

I don't know the technical name of the language feature, but you can see there are a variety of ways to make an adjective vague, and it depends on the structure of the word.

`True` can be `verdadero` or `cierto`, although `truth` is `verdad`.

Having said all that...how about `verdaderosidad` or `certizidad`? Maybe even `veracecinidad` (from `veraz` -> `veracecino`).

I like `verdaderoisdad` the most even if it's a bit long. It gives it that essential silly element.

Comment: `Verdaderoisdad` is quite good! It has the right amount of cynicism/fun.

Comment: BTW I always heard "amarillento"

Comment: stop creating words lol